# JSP website pre-database configuration

Tags: database, jsp, configuration

I'm working on a website in JSP (in GWT really, but on the server side, it's really just JSP), and I need to configure my database.

I know HOW to code in the database connection etc, but i'm wondering how/where the database config should be saved.

To clarify my doubt, let me give an example; in PHP, a website usualy has a config.php, where the user configures the database, user, etc (or an install.php generates it).

However, since JSP is bytecode, I can't code this info into my site and have the user modify it, nor can I modify it analogously to an install.php.

How should I handle this? what's the best/most common practice ? I've found **NO** examples of this. Mainly, where **should** the config file be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities to do this, what I've seen done include:

- Having database credentials in a special file, usually `db.properties` or some simple XML file that contain the required information (driver, url, username, password, any ORM parameters if needed). The properties file would be placed under `WEB-INF` or `WEB-INF/classes`; the downside of this approach is that the user would have to modify the file *inside* the WAR before deploying it to the application server.
- Acquire the database connection via JNDI and expect it to be provided by the application server. This seems to be the most common way of doing this; on the upside, your WAR doesn't have to be changed, however, the downside is that configuring a JNDI data source is different for every application server and may be confusing if your system administrators are not experienced with Java technology.

Comment: Just to be sure, since i'm a bit of a n00b at this still, WEB-INF is COMPLETELY inaccessible to outsiders right? - Placing a db.properties file generated by an install.jsp doesn't seem too far of in this case :)

Comment: Yes, it's inaccessible to outsiders. Cite out of servlet 2.5 spec: No file contained in the WEB-INF directory may
be served directly to a client by the container.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm guessing that's the best way to go! BTW: I'm planning to have a user interface for modifying the config inside the WAR, so no manual changes should be necessary.